# Como hacer que la consola no se cierre en C#

Tags: c#, windows, consola

soy nuevo en esto del tema en programación sobre C# y estoy haciendo un proyecto que se ejecuta en la consola de Windows, este mismo proyecto tiene un :
numero = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
para identificar el numero escrito pero debo apretar Enter tras haberlo escrito y ahí se me cierra la consola. Alguien que me diga si esto tiene solución,

Gracias.

Comment: que haces luego de eso? un proceso? hy luego el programa termina? agrega un console.ReadKey() al final de tu proceso y no se va a cerrar nada hasta que no apretes otra tecla... las consolas se cierran por defecto si las abre la IDE (no te va a pasar si lo ejecutad directo en la consola)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Añade la línea Console.ReadKey() para evitar que se cierre la consola.